# How to allow enter in textarea in php?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, textarea

I am using textarea in form in php.I have added validation through javascript function but it does not allow me to press enter key in textarea.I want to add to able enter key in textarea. What should i do?

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$.validator.addMethod('special', function(value) {
    return value.match(/^[ +,A-Za-z0-9_@./#-]+$/);
});
</script>
```

Please help me. Thanks in advance....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Include `\n` (newline) in the regexp:

```
$.validator.addMethod('special', function(value) {
    return value.match(/^[\n +,A-Za-z0-9_@./#-]+$/);
});
```

Comment: @BhaveshPatel If this was the answer you're looking for you should accept the asnwer. So other people knew this was what worked for you.